# NoSuchElementException in Selenium WedDriver Test

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to selenium and written a basic test to launch a website, click on link, fill form and submit.

Once it reaches to sign up page it is unable to find the "FirstName" text box. I double checked using the firebug and it is available only at one place. I even tried to identify element with xpath still getting the same error.

Here is the code using the xPath to identify first name text box.

```
package Default;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstWDWithoutRecording {

@Test
public void SouthWestSignUp() throws InterruptedException
{

    //Open the FF/Chrome browser
    //FirefoxDriver oBrw = new FirefoxDriver();
    ChromeDriver oBrw = new ChromeDriver();

    //Maximize Browser
    oBrw.manage().window().maximize();

    //Open/Launch www.southwest.com
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
    oBrw.get("http://www.southwest.com/");

    //Click on Sign up and Save
    //Recognising
    oBrw.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up")).click();

    Thread.sleep(7000);

    //Enter First Name
    oBrw.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FIRST_NAME']")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FIRST_NAME']")).sendKeys("abc");

    //Enter Last Name
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("LAST_NAME")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("LAST_NAME")).sendKeys("Kish123");

    //Enter Email ID
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("EMAIL")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("EMAIL")).sendKeys("abc@Kish123.com");

    //Selecting Home Airport
    Select uiHomeAp = new Select(oBrw.findElement(By.id("HOME_AIRPORT")));
    uiHomeAp.deselectByVisibleText("Atlanta, GA - ATL");

    //Accepting Conditions
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("IAN")).click();

    //Click Submit
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

   }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you apply your search directly to http://www.southwest.com/html/email/click_n_save_signup.html?clk=GFOOTER-CNS-ENROLL instead of being forwarded from the home page. Does that work?

Comment: no it didnt work still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

Your sign up form is located within an `<iframe>`. For Webdriver to be able to 'see' the form you'll first need to switch to that iframe.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);   //'0' as it is the only iframe on the page, the value is the index of all iframes on the page
//do your login actions
//after return
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. But selenium is unable to select the value from the drop down list.   //Selecting Home Airport
  Select uiHomeAp = new Select(oBrw.findElement(By.id("HOME_AIRPORT")));
  uiHomeAp.deselectByVisibleText("Atlanta, GA - ATL");

Comment: @KishoreJawalkar The select element is still within the 'iframe`. Don't exit that iframe, using the `.switchTo().defaultContent();` until you have completed all interactions with elements within the iframe.

Comment: @MarkRowlands  Am I only one person who is wondering how you managed to guess about iframe? :)

Comment: @olyv I once had to work on a site with nested frames within frames within frames. Nightmare!

Comment: @MarkRowlands my select statement is within iframe. But still it is not working.                               //Selecting Home Airport
  Select uiHomeAp = new Select(oBrw.findElement(By.id("HOME_AIRPORT")));
  uiHomeAp.deselectByVisibleText("Atlanta, GA - ATL");                                                              //after return
  oBrw.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: What exception/error do you receive when you try? Does it not find the select element or does it fail to find the text you wish to select?